# missing dollar inserted in a template

Tags: math-mode, errors

I am having an error called missing dollar inserted https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Errors/Missing_$_inserted

```
\author{{\bf author1$^a$} and {\bf author2^b$} and {\bf author3$^{b,c}$}\\
$^a$CSE Department, Faculty, University, Address, e-mail \\ $^b$CSE Department, Faculty, University, Address, e-mail \\
$^c$ CSE Department, Faculty, University, Address, e-mail}
```

I am using overleaf,eusflat 2019 template for paper
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/eusflat-2019-template/jmqvcrhkqhgx
so in the above code section why is this error coming I am not able to understand.

Comment: Take a look at `2^b$`. `^` for superscripts can only be used in math mode. In case of the other occurences, you used math mode by enclosing `^a` in a set of `$`. Thus, it should actually be `2$^b$` as it also is in the original template.

Comment: Do you really have to use this template? It aparently is for a conference that already took place last year? And the template seems to make use of some commands that are deprecated for years now.

Comment: no I can use anything that I want I am new to overleaf and tex so I was trying various things and I thought of using it.I downloaded texlive in a vmware virtual machine I am copying that in my local machine all setup of 6 Gb and want to do things locally on my computer. I do not know how to proceed with texlive in this situation until then I am doing things online on overleaf.

Comment: Well, then let's start with some basic questions first: Do you want to write a paper that should be submitted to a journal/conference? Do you want to write your thesis? Is it for an assignment/homework?...

Comment: I am doing it for some homework no conference I know of uses it. It is just I have to show some paper in my department so I am typing all that.

Comment: Does your department has some kind of formatting requirements? Do they tell you which documentclass to use? ...

Comment: actually no one here is knowledgeable I know of. My guide told me he will fail me if I dont give him a paper so I am writing all this.Out of 30 credits he will give me 4 or 5 grade.He does not even know the topic.

Comment: If there are no official formatting requirements given to you, why not start with a very simple example and a standard documentclass such as `article`:

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\title{title of your text}
\author{Author's name here}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{a section title}
some text that follows after the section title
\end{document}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105572/discussion-between-koeradoera-and-leandriis).

Comment: `\bf` it is a old command of TeX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @leandriis
The missing $ in 2^b$. was a problem Thus, it should actually be 2$^b$ as it also is in the original template.

Comment: Why not $2^b$? Seems more reasonable.

Comment: yes that is even better. I am reading latex tutorials .I read not so short introduction to latex
https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/
pdf of english, and watched a couple of videos here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rVt_hponBW4&list=PL1D4EAB31D3EBC449&index=3 .Now I understand why $ are used.